# VBA - MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP GET Request - Server status 416

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

I want to get HTML document structure from a website so I can extract information from it. I use GET request, but it returns 416 status. On other websites such plain GET request was enough to get a response.

```
Dim oXMLHTTP As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Dim htmlObj As New HTMLDocument

With oXMLHTTP
    .Open "GET", "http://www.manta.com/ic/mtqyfk0/ca/riverbend-holdings-inc", False
    .send

    If .ReadyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
        Set htmlObj = CreateObject("htmlFile")
        htmlObj.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        'do things
    End If

End With
```

Comment: Fixing a 416 error, and scraping a page are very different things. You should probably raise a new question so the title and tags have meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use `XMLHTTP` instead of `ServerXMLHTTP`

```
  Dim oXMLHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
```

Returns `200` for me.

Comment: Is there some considerable difference between MSXML2.XMLHTTP and MSXML2.XMLHTTP60? I have tested them performance-wise on other website and they had the same speed. ServerXMLHTTP was slightly over 2 times faster, but sadly in this case I can't use it.

Comment: IIRC it depends upon which version of the library you are referencing. I was referencing V.6, so the `XMLHTTP60` class was the available one. You could use `ServerXMLHTTP` but you'd need to provide the headers that the site appear to require, and that `XMLHTTP` *is* sending.

Comment: I was able to get `ServerXMLHTTP` to work using `.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"`